# How do I retrieve Job Info from Azure AD via MS Graph?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Hello and thanks in  advance
I'm new to MS Graph and need to retrieve Job Information in particular the Employee ID from our Azure AD. See Image.  Im not sure what the GET statement would be.  I will be using the query in Power Automate.
[Desc of AZ Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIaPY.png)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Microsoft Graph only returns a limited set of properties.

But you can use the `$select` to get other data:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=employeeId,department,jobTitle`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-users-request-using-select

Answer (score 0):

In Ms Graph you can find the  Job Information of a user by  `jobtitle` property.

**For example,**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{users UPN or object id}
```

**Responce**
[image]

Also, You can use `filter` query to retrieve  an Azure Ad user with particular job title.

**For example,**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=(jobtitle eq 'Sr Prog/Anal')
```