# Get Details of User of Azue Active Directory using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, eventual-consistency

[image]

I have queried the user endpoint using advanced query capabilities.  but I didn't get the value of Department field.

This is my query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:tobias"&ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$select=employeeId,department,jobTitle
```

The above query shows all info of the user except the info of block of job information.

Using select query for the user above:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(employeeId,department,jobTitle)",
"@odata.count": 1,
"value": [
    {
        "employeeId": null,
        "department": null,
        "jobTitle": null
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the problem about?

Comment: Please provide properly formatted text, not images/screenshots of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.

Comment: i have updated the question, and i removed the screenshot, instead i pasted the result of query. the above picture is for the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, getting the details of user from Microsoft Graph API returns only few details/properties by default.

Please refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-users-request-using-select) which confirms the same.

Please use **`$select`** to select the job details of the user like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=employeeId,department,jobTitle
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[How do I retrieve Job Info from Azure AD via MS Graph by DerDani81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382878/how-do-i-retrieve-job-info-from-azure-ad-via-ms-graph)

Comment: sorry but what i meant, i got those fields but they have no values. although you see above the Job info

Comment: i added a screen shot for the current results.

Comment: Make sure you are checking the same accounts in Portal and in Graph API and Make sure to consent User.Read.All permission.

Comment: i had checked all those points. extra i consent the permission Directory.Read.All. just attempt. unfortunately doesn't work, i got null values.

Comment: Please include properly formatted text, not images/screenshots of text. Read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, I have provided the Query in the code snippet. Only output is converted to screenshot as it is very long response.